# Generate lottery numbers - Convert R statement to Python

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I have the following function in R to generate 10 random lottery numbers:

```
 sprintf("%05d", sort(sample(0:99999, 10)))
```

output:

```
"00582" "01287" "01963" "10403" "13274" "17705" "23798" "32808" "33668" "35794"
```

I've converted it to Python like this:

```
 print(sorted(sample(range(99999), 10)))
```

output:

```
[208, 10724, 12078, 27425, 34903, 49666, 60057, 67482, 68730, 78811]
```

In the first case I get numbers of 5 digits while in the second one the numbers could have up to 5 digits, *but also less*.

So, is there any similar way to obtain a list (or string as in the first case) of 5 digits numbers?

Comment: Using `range()` with `random.sample()` is fast and memory-efficient for Python 3. But if you are using Python 2, `range()` will build an entire list of 100,000 integers in memory. Instead, use `xrange()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and `map`, for one

```
print(*map('{:05}'.format, sorted(sample(range(99999), 10))))
```

The asterisk in this context [unpacks argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). In other words it generates positional arguments from the given [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) (map in this case).

You can also store the lottery numbers as a list of strings

```
# Again using a map
ns = list(map('{:05}'.format, sorted(sample(range(99999), 10))))

# Using a list comprehension
ns = ['{:05}'.format(n) for n in sorted(sample(range(99999), 10))]
```

Note that python's [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is open as in *[start, stop)*, so use

```
range(100000)
```

for a range of values from 0 to 99999.

Comment: I like the use of  `map` and unzipping :)

Comment: One of the pros of having a print function :P It's lovely when used along with `sep=", "` for example.

Comment: @Ilja what does the asterisk before map?

Comment: The `*` operator packs and unpacks containers. In the case of `*map`... it unpacks the `iterator` that `map` generators (for python3 for python2 it unpacks a list) so instead of printing a `<map object at 0x...>` you print the content.

Comment: @Alex_Loar if the answer was suitable to your needs, would you consider accepting it?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) your `string`

```
out = []
for number in sorted(sample(range(99999), 10))):
    out.append('{:05d}'.format(number))
print(out)
```